# XMR send from Monero wallet GUI ending up on XMO chain

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

A few weeks ago (may 15) I used the local Monero GUI wallet on OSX to transfer 1.934 Monero to my Bitfinex account. I followed their instruction sending it to their BF address, adding a payment ID provided in my BF account. In the wallet this transaction was confirmed with the transaction-ID (782c48b927a21e1ae63fad532655a4226ea89cf48d3eda02f65a9352f547915d) and blockHeight (1570859).

After a few days my deposit was still not visible in BF. I got support from BF, but we couldn’t find the transaction back on the XMR blockchain. After some time mailing back and forth, we did found a transaction on the XMO chain, which had the specific transaction ID, the right date and the right block height:
https://minergate.com/blockchain/xmo/transaction/782c48b927a21e1ae63fad532655a4226ea89cf48d3eda02f65a9352f547915d

As far as I know it is not possible to send XMO with the Monero wallet.  And if I check the payment in the app, using the data from my transaction it says: 
“This address received 1.934 Monero, with 13406 confirmation(s)”
Can anybody help me out with this?

Comment: May15th?  You had upgraded to the v0.12.0 that came out on April 6th, yes?  If it was sent on the old blockchain (v0.11.x) kinda makes sense to me.  I *beleive* you can upgrade to the correct blockchain and resend.

Comment: Use that ^ guide to resolve your issue. Furthermore, the funds should be back in your wallet after applying aforementioned guide.

Comment: Thanks for your reactions! No I had not upgraded to v.0.12. I didn't no it was available. I'm going to try the guide deBUYNE refers to. I let you know if this works.

Comment: I followed the guide mentioned above. I took some time but in the end my fonds appeared back in the wallet. Thanks a lot!